# "Cannot find the path specified" when setting up patent crawler

Tags: python, command-line, syntax-error

I am trying to set up the [wenyalintw patent scraper](https://github.com/wenyalintw/Google-Patents-Scraper). I got everything installed. I then go to execute the command `cd src main.py` and it tells me the system cannot find the path specified.

I tried changing it to `cd src "path to main.py"` and it tells me the filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

Did I break it? How do I run the scraper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're combining two commands. At the end of the [Getting Started](https://github.com/wenyalintw/Google-Patents-Scraper#getting-started) section, it says to run:

```bash
cd src
python main.py
```

These are two separate commands. The first changes the current working directory to the `src` directory, which contains a file named `main.py`. *After* doing that, the second command runs the file `main.py`.

Comment: Idk why I over looked that. Broke it up into the 2 and now I get a new error. Path to main.py, line 1, in <modual> from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QDesktopServices ModualeNotFoundError: No Module named 'PyQt5'

Comment: @Grendal87 Just saw the edit to your comment. Looks like you don't ave PyQt5 installed. `pip install PyQt5`? You need the dependencies to run this tool. If installing them doesn't help, that sounds like a new question. (Be sure to link to the library you've dowloaded and include the full stack trace that comes with the error message.)

Comment: Also perhaps look up some introductory Python tutorials, especially about installing and using tools/libraries.